# Is there a way to determine when an external program closes?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, process, external

I am using vb.net to open a Word document like this:

```
process.start("mydoc.docx")
```

This works to open the document in Word. But I need to know when they close the document so I can check its size to see if the size changed (which means they edited it).

Is there a way to determine when my process ends or something similar?

Thanks.

Comment: The user can save and close the document without exiting Word. There is no way to tell when Word has saved the document without monitoring the *last modified* date on the file itself. You should search this site for questions related to monitoring a folder for changes - there are existing questions here that cover that on Windows.

Comment: Or, you could open the Document with Office.Interop, so you can handle the `Document.Close` event (or the `Application.DocumentBeforeSave` event etc.)

Comment: To address the specific question (rather than your larger desired workflow), yes, you can be notified when the process ends.  See the `Exited` event on the process object.